# Save Html Dropdownlist value after POST MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, postback

I have a Dropdown list that is filled with data from my sql db, and i have a html form with POST everytime the user selects a option from my Dropdown list, however each time page refreshes i get my Dropdownlist default on screen instead of the last item the user picks how can i save the last value the user pics to stay on screen after a POST?

This is my Viewbag:

```
foreach (var item in db.Pos.Select(l => l.Fecha).Distinct())
        {
           dateday = item.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
           lines = dateday.Split(' ')[0];
           listItem2.Add(lines);
        }
        var fechas = new SelectList(listItem2.ToList());
        ViewBag.Fechas = fechas;
```

And this is my View Code:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "home/index", FormMethod.Post, new {id="some" }))
      { 
     <input type="hidden" name="txtInput" value=""/>

      @Html.DropDownList("Fechas", "Todas")

      <input type="submit" name="test" value="Calcula Totales"/>  
      }
```

I want the value of my ' @Html.DropDownList("Fechas", "Todas")' be the last one the user selects instead of the default "Todas"

Comment: Then you need to bind you dropdownlist to a model property - `@HtmlDropDownListFor(m = m.someProperty, (SelectList)ViewBag.Fechas, "Todas")` and set the value of `someProperty` to a value in the controller before you pass the model to the view.

Comment: And what do you think `lines = dateday.Split(' ')[0];` is doing? - you may as well use `listItem2.Add(dateday);` since `lines` is exactly the same value as `dateday`

Answer (score 1):

Use overloaded version of **@Html.DropDownList**
Example:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("itemStatus", new SelectList(Model.lstSelectList, "Value", "Text", item.StatusCode))
```

where item.StatusCode is the Previous Selected Value. You need to pass it From controller either using Viewbag,Viewdata etc.Better you pass it in model itself

Or

Use **DropDownListFor** .

```
You should do like this:

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ContribType, 
                new SelectList(Model.ContribTypeOptions, 
                               "ContribId", "Value"))
```

Where:

```
m => m.ContribType
```

is a property where the result value will be. 
And the last param of Select list constructor is a selected value

Comment: If `lstSelectList` is already `SelectList`, why on earth would you create another identical `SelectList` from it. And since this is not binding to anything, it would not work anyway.

Comment: Brother that's the syntax when you want to set selected value using DropDownList Html helper, where item.StatusCode is the previous selected value.
The Thing is when you are posting your form, take Model object as an input parameter in your post method. And Pass it to the VIew

Comment: See the Updated Answer

Comment: It is not. If you want to bind to the property `StatusCode`, then its `@Html.DropDownListFor(m = m.StatusCode, Model.lstSelectList)`. When you bind to a property, its the value of the property that determines what is selected! Adding the last parameter in the `SelectList` constructor is ignored by the helper - its just pointless

Comment: I have added both ways Now.

Comment: The first one is wrong, and the second one (assuming `ContribTypeOptions` is not `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`) still has the pointless last parameter.